# Почему нельзя вернуть значение из символьного массива, преобразив его в строку?

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, преобразование

Данный код - решение задачи по работе со строками. Ее суть, подобно ДНК продемонстрировать принцип комплементарности, принимая в методе строчный аргумент, и возвращая строку, в которой, все A заменены на T, все T заменены на А, все G заменены на C, и, соответственно, все C на G. Т.е. "ATAGCA" -> "TATCGT"
В приведенном ниже коде закомментированны строчки кода, который я написал изначально. Они не работают. Строка, следующая за ними, справляется со своей задачей прекрасно. Объясните мне пожалуйста, почему это происходит.

```
class DnaStrand {
    public String makeComplement(String dna) {
        char DNAArr[] = dna.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < DNAArr.length; i++) {
            switch (DNAArr[i]) {
                case 'A':
                    DNAArr[i] = 'T';
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    DNAArr[i] = 'A';
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    DNAArr[i] = 'C';
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    DNAArr[i] = 'G';
                    break;
            }
        }
        //String OtherSide = new String();
        //OtherSide = DNAArr.toString();
        //return OtherSide;
        return new String(DNAArr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем выкладывать некомпилируемый код и лишние строчки?

Comment: `static Dictionary<char, char> tr = new Dictionary<char, char> { ['A'] = 'T', ['T'] = 'A', ['G'] = 'C', ['C'] = 'G' }; public string MakeComplement(string dna) => new string(dna.Select(c => tr[c]).ToArray());`

Answer (score 3):

Потому что метод [`Array.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) не предназначен для конкатенации символов массива.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @HarryB. Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers